# Event broadcasting in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there a way to have a event delivered to every subscriber of a topic regardless of consumer group? think "Refresh your local cache" kind of scenario

Comment: Surely just pushing to a topic would do this, as all the consumer groups would get it?

Are you trying to having multiple schemas on the same topic is that the underlying issue?

Comment: not only all consumer groups, but rather all consumers subscribed to a consumer group (all machines/processes)

Comment: Have you thought about using redis for this? I can’t immediately think of a way to achieve this.

Comment: I did yeah sure, the thing is that I don't want to include a redis dependency ONLY for this reason...

Comment: The only solution I can think of is having a second consumer group which also has the machine name in it, and then filtering out the events so you don't process them multiple times.

I.E MainConsumer group does all the normal kafka stuff etc. and then a second Main{MACHINENAME} that filters out all the other messages. That way you'll definitely get the cache event on all machines. You could also use this for other control events if you put the machine name in the event payload.

Comment: Can you explain the use-case better? A single event will only go to **one** consumer thread in each subscribed consumer group. If you want a cache, which is updated from a topic, that you later query, this is what Interactive Queries feature of Kafka Streams is for

Comment: @OneCricketeer imagine that your super posted a eviction noticed under your door. Anyone one who lives you can get it from under the door, but everyone in your residence needs to leave, not only the person who got the message. Thats what I need, reach EVERY consumer on a group and not only A consumer. as RubbleFord said, redis Pub/Sub fits the bill, but I wouldn't like to add it to my solution ONLY for this purpose... I thought perhaps I could get the same result with Kafka somehow

Comment: Yeah, no, Kafka doesn't have fan-out consumption, but like I said, anything can periodically poll a KTable exposed over RPC, regardless of consumer group

Comment: @OneCricketeer can you post that as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as Kafka in concerned, you cannot subscribe to a topic without a consumer group.

Out of the box, this isn't a pattern of a Kafka consumer; there isn't a way to make all consumers in a group read all messages from all partitions. There cannot be more consumer clients than partitions (thereby making "fan out" hard), and only one message goes to any one consumer before the message offset gets committed and the entire consumer group seeks those offsets forward to consume later events.

You'd need a layer above the consumer to decouple yourself from the consumer-group limitations.

For example, with [Interactive Queries](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html), you'd consume a topic and build a StateStore from the data that comes in, effectively building a distributed cache. With that, you can layer in an RPC layer (mentioned in those docs) that allows external applications over a protocol of your choice (e.g. HTTP) to later query and poll that data. From an application that is polling the data, you then would have the option of forwarding "notification events" via any method of your choice.

As for a framework that already exposes most of this out-of-the-box, checkout [Azkarra Streams](https://azkarrastreams.io) (I have no affiliation)

---

Or you can use alternative solutions such as Kafka Connect and write data to Slack, Telegram, etc. "message boards" instead, where many people explicitly subscribe to those channel notifications.